# how to select by max(date) with spark dataframe API

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given the following dataset

```
id v  date
1  a1 1
1  a2 2
2  b1 3
2  b2 4
```

I want to select only the last value (regarding the date) for each id.

I've came up with this code :

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(List((41,"a1",1), (1, "a2", 2), (2, "b1", 3), (2, "b2", 4))).toDF("id", "v", "date")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, v: string, date: int]

scala> val agg = df.groupBy("id").max("date")
agg: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, max(date): int]

scala> val res = df.join(agg, df("id") === agg("id") && df("date") === agg("max(date)"))
16/11/14 22:25:01 WARN sql.Column: Constructing trivially true equals predicate, 'id#3 = id#3'. Perhaps you need to use aliases.
res: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, v: string, date: int, id: int, max(date): int]
```

Is there a better way (more idiomatic, …) ?

Bonus : how to perform a max on a date column and avoid this error  `Aggregation function can only be applied on a numeric column.` ?

Comment: You can try `from_unixtime` function to apply `agg` on date field.

Comment: I'm not sure this works, but worth to try SQL: select max(date) as mdate, id from tmp_table group by id;

Answer (score 5):

You can try `agg()` with the max function :

`import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*
df.groupBy("id").agg(max("date"))`

Answer (score 0):

For me it only worked taht way:

```
df = df.groupBy('CPF').agg({'DATA': 'max'})
```